# Retrieve Calling Method & Metadata from Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is it possible to retrieve from inside a given method any information about the method that called it?

```
public void MethodOne()
{
   for (int nCount = 0; nCount < 10; nCount++) MethodTwo();
}
public void MethodTwo()
{
   // Can I retrieve here information about the call to MethodOne which originated this call?
}
```

For example, in this situation I would like to be able to know at runtime that a given set of ten calls to `MethodTwo` were originated from a call to `MethodOne` in a given thread... Is this possible?

Comment: Do you only want to count direct calls? What if Method1 calls Foo, then Foo calls Bar, and Bar calls MethodTwo?

Comment: You might not like it, but calling `Method2("MethodOne")` (or some other way of expressing the origin) is arguably a sane mechanism here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is horrible:

```
string caller0 = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name; // MethodOne
string caller1 = new StackFrame(2).GetMethod().Name; // whatever called MethodOne
```

(this also doesn't come free; any such abuse has a performance price)

Comment: Also worth noting that in addition to the performance cost, this is potentially unreliable too: the jitter could decide to inline any of those methods.

Comment: Not for a delegate call though.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, though it is possible if you examine the current stack trace:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// ...

StackTrace t = new StackTrace();
```

If you need your code to behave differently depending on who the caller is, you should have an extra parameter to your method that the caller can use to identify themselves.

If you are using this information to debug your application then you might instead wish to use a profiler that can tell you this sort of information without you having to modify your code.